# C# Linq to Xml Sort elements inside a node

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

My xml file looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Child>
        <SubChild>
            <Item Sequence="2">Value2</Item>
            <Item Sequence="1">Value1</Item>
            <Node Sequence="1">First</Node>
            <Node Sequence="3">Third</Node>
            <Node Sequence="2">Second</Node>
            <Url>https://url.com</Url>
        </SubChild>
    <Child>
</Root>
```

I want my result to be in this order

```
<Root>
    <Child>
        <SubChild>
            <Item Sequence="1">Value1</Item>
            <Item Sequence="2">Value2</Item>
            <Node Sequence="1">First</Node>
            <Node Sequence="2">Second</Node>
            <Node Sequence="3">Third</Node>
            <Url>https://url.com</Url>
        </SubChild>
    <Child>
</Root>
```

I can get to the node all fine. I am having issues sorting them while maintaining the element position. How can I order the nodes Item and Node and still maintain their order within the SubChild node? I need Items to the first node, followed by Node, and then Url.

This is what I tried.

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xdoc.OuterXml);

var subChild = doc.Descendants("Root").Descendants("Child").Descendants("SubChild");
subChild.Elements("Item").OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("Sequence")));
subChild.Elements("Node").OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("Sequence")));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the `<SubChild>` element with XPath: "/Root/Child/SubChild" (`subChild`). This will be used for the updation later.
2. Extract the descendants in the `<SubChild>` element.
3. Order the result from *1* by `LocalName` from the element (comparing the element index in the `elementOrder` array), then by `Sequence`.
4. Update the node in `subChild` via `.ReplaceNode()`.

```cs
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

var subChild = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Root/Child/SubChild");
var subChildDesc = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Root/Child/SubChild").Descendants();
        
string[] elementOrder = new string[] { "Item", "Node", "Url" };
        
subChildDesc = subChildDesc
    .OfType<XElement>()
    .OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(elementOrder, x.Name.LocalName))
    .ThenBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("Sequence")?.Value.ToString()))
    .ToList();
        
subChild.ReplaceNodes(subChildDesc);
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxTUNB)